# Django caching in a custom context processor

Tags: django, caching

I have a custom context processor which I use to generate a dynamic menu and a list of current apps, site-wide:

```
from portal.models import *

def base_items(request):
    return { 
        ...
        'app_items': App.objects.filter(isonline=True), 
        'menu_items': MainMenu.objects.all().order_by('position'),
    }
```

EDIT:

My template (note that many of these urls are outside of the Django framework and vary depending on language. Hence the need to hardcode them into the db fields:

```
<ul class="menu">
            {% for item in menu_items %}
                {% if LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us" %}
                <li><a title="{{ item.title_en }}" href="{{ item.url_en }}">{{ item.title_en }}</a>
                    <ul>
                    {% for subitem in item.submenu_set.all %}
                        <li><a title="{{ subitem.title_en }}" href="{{ subitem.url_en }}">{{ subitem.title_en }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    {% else %}
                <li><a title="{{ item.title_es }}" href="{{ item.url_es }}">{{ item.title_es }}</a>
                    <ul>
                    {% for subitem in item.submenu_set.all %}
                <li><a title="{{ subitem.title_es }}" href="{{ subitem.url_es }}">{{ subitem.title_es }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}        
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}    
            </ul>
```

My question is - how can I cache these results, which don't change very frequently?

I have tried the @cache_page decorator but I can see my pages still accessing the db for the menu items objects.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use django [low level cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api). Note that you might have to [cast the querysets to list](http://www.indirecthit.com/2008/04/28/django-caching-querysets/).

**Or**, you could [cache the template fragment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#template-fragment-caching) that uses these querysets, because [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: hmmm. I tried with the template caching and it doesn't respect the language state. See edit.

Comment: You can cache the template fragment with respect to current language by passing the language to {% cache %} templatetag. Like this:
``{% cache 600 welcome LANGUAGE_CODE %}
      {% trans "Welcome to example.com" %}
  {% endcache %}``

Answer (score 1):

Try to return lamdas expressions to your templates:

```
 'app_items': lambda: App.objects.filter(isonline=True),
```

that way it does not get compiled/cached and works dynamically.